# Wordpress regular expression redirect with redirect plugin

Tags: redirects, wordpress

I need to redirect all traffic for a suspended site and what I have tried so far is installing the [redirect plugin](https://redirection.me/support/redirect-regular-expressions/) and adding a redirect (tools->redirection->add new

```
source: ^/(?!.*login.*|under_construction)(.*)
target: /under_construction
```

But while it redirects all traffic to `under_construction` correctly, and does not redirect `under_construction` (recursively), the login exclusion isn't working so it also redirects the login to `under_construction`, so I can't log in or out.

`https://example.com/wordpress/wp-login.php` to `https://example.com/under_construction`

Fortunately, it wouldn't let me log out, and did not affect the other admin pages, so I was able to disable it. :-)

Comment: The regex could be simplified a bit, but otherwise, it looks OK to me. I think the problem is "something else". Are URLs that contain "login" the only required exception?

Comment: @MrWhite yeah, and it's a bit odd, as none of the other /wordpress/ pages are redirected, just the login

Comment: So, it's not even redirecting the pages that should be redirected? Presumably you are using the default config whereby WordPress is handling the redirection, not Apache (or Nginx)?

Comment: @MrWhite - with that regex enabled, it redirects all traffic to the correct page, but also redirects the login/logout page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend adjusting the parenthesis in your regex.   Specifically, it isn't clear to me how much of the `.*login.*` is being viewed as a single group before the "or" (`|`).   I'd put parenthesis around that and around `under_construction` for good measure.

You don't need parenthesis around the final `.*` because that will stand fine on its own and you are not using that as a capturing group.

Try: `^/(?!(.*login.*)|(under_construction)).*`

Comment: There must have been something else?! The additional parenthesis in this example make no difference in terms of whether the regex (PCRE) matches (or not). _Alternation_ ("or") has very low precedence and `*` (_quantifier_) has very high precedence; `.*login.*` will be seen as "one group" regardless. The additional parens are arguably undesirable as they create two additional (unnecessary) capturing groups (1 and 2) that will always be empty. Maybe there was a caching issue? Or maybe the WP redirection plugin does something "funny" with the regex first (although that would seem unlikely)?